# Azure hosting Workflow Activity with Persistence for Windows8 Push Notification

Tags: azure, windows-8, workflow-foundation-4

I'm completely new to the Windows Azure and Windows Workflow scope of things.

But basically, what I'm trying to implement is the Cloud web-app that's going to be responsible for pushing down tile updates/badge/toast notifications to my Winodws 8 application.

The code to run to send down the tile notification etc is fine, but needs to be executed every  hour or so.

I decided the most straight forward approach was to make an MVC application that would have a WebAPI, this WebAPI will be responsible for receiving the ChannelURI from the ModernApplication that sends it to it, and will be stored on SQL Azure.

There will then be a class that has a static method which does the logic for gathering the new data and generating a new Tile/Badge/Toast.

I've created a simple Activity workflow, that has a Sequence with a DoWhile(true) activity. Inside the body of this DoWhile, contains a Sequence which has InvokeMethod and Delay, the InvokeMethod will call my class that contains the static method. The delay is set to one hour.

So that seems to be all okay. I then start this Activity via the Application_Start in Global.asax with the following line:

```
    this.ActivityInvoker = new WorkflowInvoker(new NotificationActivity());
    this.ActivityInvoker.InvokeAsync();
```

So I just tested it with that and it seems to be running my custom static method at the set interval.

That's all good, but now I have three questions in relation to this way of handling it:

- Is this the correct/best approach to do this? If not, what are some other ways I should look into.
- If a new instance is spun up on Azure, how do I ensure that the running Workflow for both instances won't step on each other's foot? i.e. how do I make sure that the InvokeMethod won't run two times, I only want it to run once an hour regardless of how many instances there are.
- How do I ensure that if the instances crash/go-down that the state of it is maintained?

Any help, guidance, etc is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of good questions that I would love to answer, however trying to do some on a forum like this would be difficult. But let's give it a crack. To start with at least.

1) There is nothing wrong with your approach for implementing a scheduled task. I can think of a few other ways of doing it. Like running a simple Worker Role with a Do{Thread.Sleep(); ...} simple, but effective. There are more complex / elegant ways too including using external libraries and frameworks for scheduling tasks in Azure.

2) You would need to implement some sort of Singleton type pattern in your workflow / job processing engine. You could for instance acquire a lease on a 1Kb blob record when your job starts, and not allow another instance to start etc.

For more detailed answers I suggest we take this offline and have a Skype call and discuss in detail your requirements. You know how to get hold of me via email :) look forward to it.

Comment: I do not think that suggesting you solve the problem offline is a good answer on stack overflow, it does nothing to help future users.